# what query to use in this situation- sqlServer

Tags: sql-server

I haves 2 tables:

Info:

[image]

Score:

[image]

What query can i use to get this result?
( The months and years column show the score of the guys in June-2019
[image]

Comment: If you haven't tried anything yet, why not? What research have you done? If you don't know where to start, I suggest looking up `JOIN` syntax; it's one of the fundamental parts of using any RDBMS.

Comment: i think i have to group by id then count the 2019 values, but i don't know how, i'm newbie

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this

```
SELECT 
    Info.id
    , Info.Name
    , Info.age
    , DATEDIFF(MONTH, CAST(score.date AS datetime), GETDATE()) AS Moths
    , DATEDIFF(YEAR, CAST(score.date AS datetime), GETDATE()) AS Years
FROM 
    Info 
    INNER JOIN Score
    ON Info.id = Score.ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
select info.id, info.name,info.age, sum(case when MONTH(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 6 and Year(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 2019 then score else 0 end) as monthS,sum(case when MONTH(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 6 and Year(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 2019 then score else 0 end) as  yearS
from info
inner join score
on info.id = score.id
group by info.id, info.name,info.age
```

OR:

```
select info.id, info.name,info.age, sum(isnull(score,0)) as monthS,sum(isnull(score,0)) as  yearS
from info
left join
(
    select * from score
    where MONTH(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 6 and Year(convert(datetime,score.date,5)) = 2019
 ) as s
on info.id = s.id
group by info.id, info.name,info.age
```

Example working [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=4fe27af94c7c5d4c95afe0a7b904dd16).